# Want to show a message on mouse hover on a date

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have used the following .net code. Which shows the holiday date which I store in database.
But i want to show some message when I hover the mouse on the date.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
string connection = @"server=TOPHAN-PC; Database=Tophan;uid=sa;pwd=123";
SqlConnection con = null;
protected DataSet dsHolidays;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {

        con = new SqlConnection(connection);
        Calendar1.VisibleDate = DateTime.Today;
        FillHolidayDataset();
    }
}

protected void FillHolidayDataset()
{
    DateTime firstDate = new DateTime(Calendar1.VisibleDate.Year,      Calendar1.VisibleDate.Month, 1);
    DateTime lastDate = GetFirstDayOfNextMonth();
    dsHolidays = GetCurrentMonthData(firstDate, lastDate);
}

protected DateTime GetFirstDayOfNextMonth()
{
    int monthNumber, yearNumber;
    if (Calendar1.VisibleDate.Month == 12)
    {
        monthNumber = 1;
        yearNumber = Calendar1.VisibleDate.Year + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        monthNumber = Calendar1.VisibleDate.Month + 1;
        yearNumber = Calendar1.VisibleDate.Year;
    }
    DateTime lastDate = new DateTime(yearNumber, monthNumber, 1);
    return lastDate;
}

protected DataSet GetCurrentMonthData(DateTime firstDate, DateTime lastDate)
{
    DataSet dsMonth = new DataSet();
    try
    {            
        //ConnectionStringSettings cs;
        //cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString1"];
        //String connString = cs.ConnectionString;
        //SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection(connString);

        String query = "SELECT CDate FROM calender  WHERE CDate >= @firstDate AND  CDate < @lastDate";
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand dbCommand = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        dbCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@firstDate",
            firstDate));
        dbCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@lastDate", lastDate));

        SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(dbCommand);
        sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dsMonth);                       
    }
    catch
    { }
    return dsMonth;
}


protected void Calendar1_VisibleMonthChanged(object sender,
    MonthChangedEventArgs e)
{
    FillHolidayDataset();
}
protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        DateTime nextDate;
        if (dsHolidays != null)
        {
            foreach (DataRow dr in dsHolidays.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                nextDate = (DateTime)dr["CDate"];
                if (nextDate == e.Day.Date)
                {
                    e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Pink;

                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    { }
}
}
```

By using this code,I find out that it highlighted the date with the color but I want some message when I move the mouse on the Date.

Comment: do you want to display some static message? if yes then you can easily do it with jQuery ! and even in dynamic message, you'll be able to do it with jQuery if the dynamic content is somewhere on page.

Comment: Any one there to help me on this query.

Comment: If I will able to set some static messages,then later I can make it Dynamic.So if you have the jQuery code will you please share the code. @Aisha

Comment: I had used the default asp.net calender control in my page. So where I have to used this code & which version of jQuery I have to link in the page. @Aisha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it by this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{       
  $("#holiday").hover(function () {
    //Show whatever message on hover in 
  },
  function () {
    //Show whatever message on hover out
  }
); });
```

Comment: I had used the default asp.net calender control in my page. So where I have to used this code & which default jQuery I have to link in the page. @Aisha